# What happened to Bran and Hodor?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

As the title suggests, what happened to Bran and Hodor in *Game of Thrones*? Why are they not featured in season 5? Did their story end? If not, will they be playing an important role in the future? Because until season 5 Bran is shown as a very important character and seems as if he can be a game changer in the future.

Comment: I'm more curious why the scriptwriters seem to have completely forgotten about any Ironborn other than Reek nee Theon Greyjoy since forever... there's plenty of storyline left on that end.

Comment: @neminem: They're tight on screen time, and it's not necessary to show the moot.  They can just have a character in Season 6 spend 30 seconds explaining the result of the moot.

Comment: There are [speculations (based on the casting news)](http://watchersonthewall.com/game-of-thrones-season-6-casting-has-begun-and-heres-the-list/)  that they will appear in Season 6.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no more book material available for Bran and the writers decided that he won't be shown in Season 5 at all, so they won't advance his story too far.

Writer David Benioff [said](http://screencrush.com/game-of-thrones-season-5-bran-not-appearing-confirmed/):

> The fact is, even though we’re making changes to the books and
>   adapting as necessary, we’re trying to keep the various storylines the
>   same as the books and trying to keep them roughly [chronologically]
>   parallel. And last year we caught up to the end of Bran’s storyline
>   [in George R.R. Martin’s most recent A Song of Ice and Fire novel, A
>   Dance with Dragons]. So if we pushed him forward this season, then
>   he’s way ahead of where the other characters are.
>
> It made sense to stop where we did. He’s now entering a training
>   period which is going to take quite some time, much of which isn’t
>   particularly cinematic. So rather than being stuck in a cave for a
>   year, we figured it would be interesting to leave him out for a little
>   bit.

Comment: So he does have a role to play but author has not written about it yet?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Exactly.